# UI design - Trying to come up with some UI design ideas for a mobile app layout

Tags: user-interface

I am looking for some design ideas for a layout. Are there any web sites that people here would recommend that I should refer? The app is simply a question and answer type app. There is a question with 4 answers as a radio button.

Any help would be appreciated

thanks

Comment: I don't think you have many choices, here: you would have a label at the top with the question, followed by radio buttons laid out from top-to-bottom. By "design" are you actually referring to the graphics etc. (i.e. the "look" rather than the "feel")?

Comment: yea - i do mean the look. Are there some websites with free images that i could maybe use?

Answer (score 0):

[**jQuery mobile**](http://jquerymobile.com/) if you are looking for what to use.
I don't think that anyone here will tell you how to design it. It's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of resources that may help: http://mobilegui.net and http://iphoneized.com